# Downloading PDF from .NET controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, angularjs, pdf

Okay, I've read just about every Stack Overflow question on PDF downloading from a web service. None of them have helped me so far. I'm using this as a last ditch effort to try and get some answers. Basically, I'm making a GET request to the API, and need to get a dynamically generated PDF back. We've tried doing this with receiving a `byte[]` and now we're returning a stream with the content. The following is what we have in the web service controller:

```
var result = await resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<byte[]>();
var response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
var dataStream = new MemoryStream(result);
response.Content = new StreamContent(dataStream);
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "idcard.pdf";

var fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\temp.pdf", FileMode.Create);
fileStream.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
fileStream.Close();

return response;
```

The FileStream part is a test we were doing to see if saving the data to a temporary file worked and that the PDF can be saved. That part does work. Going to c:\temp and opening the idcard.pdf file works perfectly. One of the problems with that is it does it silently and the user wouldn't know it's there. We can tell them, but we'd really prefer the PDF to open in the browser by default and/or have it save through the browser so they knew something happened.

My Angular code looks like this:

```
.factory('memberIdCard', ['$http', function($http) {

var get = function() {
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/Member/IdCard',
        headers: {
            accept: 'application/octet-stream'
        },
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        transformResponse: function(data) {
            var pdf;
            console.log('data: ', data);
            if (data) {
                pdf = new Blob([data], {
                    type: 'application/pdf'
                });
                console.log('pdf: ', pdf);
            }
            return pdf;
        }
    })
}

return {
    get: get
}
}]);
```

I have tried this part with `$http` and `$resource` and neither works. Now, in my controller:

```
$scope.printIdCard = function() {
memberIdCard.get().then(function(data) {
    var pdf = data.data;
    FileSaver.saveAs(pdf, 'idcard.pdf');

    var pdfUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(pdf);

    $scope.pdfView = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(pdfUrl);
    window.open($scope.pdfView);

});
```

As a note, `FileSaver` is from [angular-file-saver](https://github.com/alferov/angular-file-saver).

After all that, the new window opens, but there's an error that says: Failed to load PDF Document, and if you try and open it in Adobe Acrobat it has an error that says: Adobe Acrobat Reader DC could not open 'idcard.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I feel like I've done everything that was suggested in many of the other SO questions, but maybe I'm missing something I just haven't been able to see.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar for .xlsx files, but the concept is the same. Hope this can help you, its working for me.

I got the javascript code to download the file from another SO answer, which I can't link because I don't remember where it was.

My web api controller looks like this:

```
[Route("all")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetAll(HttpRequestMessage request)
{

HttpResponseMessage response = null;

MemoryStream stream = _exportService.CreateDataStream();

response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.GetBuffer());
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
response.Content.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

return response;


}
```

And the angular service:

```js
(function (app) {

  'use strict';

  app.factory('exportService', exportService);

  exportService.$inject = ['$q', '$http'];

  function exportService($q, $http) {

    var extension = '.xlsx';

    var service = {
        export: exportData
    };

    function exportData(event, fname){

        var config = {
            responseType: 'arraybuffer'
        }

        var path = 'api/export/'+event;

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        return $http.get(path, config).then(
            function(response) {

                var data = response.data;
                var status = response.status;
                var headers = response.headers();

                var octetStreamMime = 'application/octet-stream';
                var success = false;

                var filename = fname + extension;

                var contentType = headers['content-type'] || octetStreamMime;

                try
                {
                    // Try using msSaveBlob if supported
                    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });
                    if(navigator.msSaveBlob)
                        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
                    else {
                        // Try using other saveBlob implementations, if available
                        var saveBlob = navigator.webkitSaveBlob || navigator.mozSaveBlob || navigator.saveBlob;
                        if(saveBlob === undefined) throw "Not supported";
                        saveBlob(blob, filename);
                    }
                    success = true;
                    deferred.resolve();
                } catch(ex)
                {
                }

                if(!success)
                {
                    // Get the blob url creator
                    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.mozURL || window.msURL;
                    if(urlCreator)
                    {
                        // Try to use a download link
                        var link = document.createElement('a');
                        if('download' in link)
                        {
                            // Try to simulate a click
                            try
                            {
                                // Prepare a blob URL
                                var blob = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });
                                var url = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
                                link.setAttribute('href', url);

                                // Set the download attribute (Supported in Chrome 14+ / Firefox 20+)
                                link.setAttribute("download", filename);

                                // Simulate clicking the download link
                                var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
                                event.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                                link.dispatchEvent(event);
                                success = true;
                                deferred.resolve();
                            } catch(ex) {
                            }
                        }

                        if(!success)
                        {
                            // Fallback to window.location method
                            try
                            {
                                var blob = new Blob([data], { type: octetStreamMime });
                                var url = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
                                window.location = url;
                                success = true;
                                deferred.resolve();
                            } catch(ex) {
                                deferred.reject();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                return deferred.promise;
            },
            function(error) {
                return $q.reject(error);
            });
    }

    return service;
  }

})(angular.module('core.module'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and for reaching out. I implemented all of it and it still didn't turn out to help me. I think it's basically doing what angular-file-saver does, just in a different way. There must be something else on our end that's going wrong and keeping it from working.